# Node.js - blocking while loop to receive input from stdin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, blocking, synchronous

I'm learning plain JavaScript on the command line, using Node.js to execute my scripts.

I've been trying to rewrite a simple Ruby implementation of ['Towers of Hanoi'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi).

Here is some of my code so far:

```
function Tower() {
  this.rods = [[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [], []];
  this.gameOver = false;
}

Tower.prototype.showTowers = function () {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i + 1 + ': ' + this.rods[i]);
  }
};

Tower.prototype.moveRod = function (from, to) {
  ...
}
```

I am struggling with writing the play loop. I think the issue is that I'm not familiar with asynchronous functions. My play loop pseudocode is something like:

```
until game.win? {
  game.show_towers
  until valid_move?(move) {
    move = request_move
  }
  make_move(move)
}
game.congrats
```

I've tried [prompt](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-prompt) and [readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html). I'm assuming neither are 'blocking' because in both cases my while loop infinitely cycles through user input requests repeatedly without stopping.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some real loop-code that you've tried? The pseudocode is logically correct, you just need to use callbacks and recursion instead of a loop. [Async's until](https://github.com/caolan/async#until) might make the code cleaner.

Comment: maybe you should consider use some kind of a cli module. look here for a nice example: https://blog.nodejitsu.com/writing-cli-apps-with-flatiron

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js: readSync from stdin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430939/node-js-readsync-from-stdin)