# press any key to continue in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, keypress

I need a function that will pause the execution of the script until a key is pressed. 
I've tried:

```
var stdin = process.openStdin(); 
require('tty').setRawMode(true);    

stdin.on('keypress', function (chunk, key) {
  process.stdout.write('Get Chunk: ' + chunk + '\n');
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') process.exit();
});
```

but it's just listening for a keypress and nothing happens. The program does not continue executing.

How can I pause execution?

Comment: You can't pause the execution of script running in background. But I don't think that is the point, you need to pause the process.stdin/stdout. You can look into [readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) package.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Works for me:

```
console.log('Press any key to exit');

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on('data', process.exit.bind(process, 0));
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the question, this kills the program on a keypress, the question was to pause and then resume on a keypress.

Comment: I got in `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)`  `TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'setRawMode'`

Comment: You have to put process.stdin.setRawMode=true instead of function

Comment: Watch out if you're using `nodemon`!! `process.stdin.setRawMode` may be `undefined`.

Answer (score 57):

In node.js 7.6 and later you can do this:

```
const keypress = async () => {
  process.stdin.setRawMode(true)
  return new Promise(resolve => process.stdin.once('data', () => {
    process.stdin.setRawMode(false)
    resolve()
  }))
}

;(async () => {

  console.log('program started, press any key to continue')
  await keypress()
  console.log('program still running, press any key to continue')
  await keypress()
  console.log('bye')

})().then(process.exit)
```

Or if you want CTRL-C to exit the program but any other key to continue normal execution, then you can replace the "keypress" function above with this function instead:

```
const keypress = async () => {
  process.stdin.setRawMode(true)
  return new Promise(resolve => process.stdin.once('data', data => {
    const byteArray = [...data]
    if (byteArray.length > 0 && byteArray[0] === 3) {
      console.log('^C')
      process.exit(1)
    }
    process.stdin.setRawMode(false)
    resolve()
  }))
}
```

Comment: If using the latest TypeScript version, select `ES6` for `tsconfig,json` and change `then(process.exit)` to `then(()=>process.exit(0))`.

Comment: For some reason the program was exiting at the `process.stdin.once` call. Adding the `process.stdin.resume()` after `setRawMode(true)`, as suggested on @vkurchatkin answer, solved it. (Node 14.16.0)

Answer (score 16):

The accepted solution waits asynchronously for a key event and then exits, it is not really a solution to "Press any key to continue".

I needed to pause while writing some nodejs shell scripts. I ended up using the spawnSync of the child_process with the shell command "read".

This will basically pause the script and when you press Enter it will continue. Much like the pause command in windows.

```
require('child_process').spawnSync("read _ ", {shell: true, stdio: [0, 1, 2]});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For Windows replace `"read _ "` with `"pause"`. I check `process.platform` to set it based on the platform.

Comment: simple and elegant

Answer (score 13):

This snippet does the job if you don't want to exit the process:

```js
console.log('Press any key to continue.');
process.stdin.once('data', function () {
  continueDoingStuff();
});
```

It's async so won't work inside loop as-is-- if you're using Node 7 you could wrap it in a promise and use `async/await`.

Comment: Great no-nonsense stuff. You saved my afternoon.

Answer (score 7):

There is a package for this:
[press-any-key](https://www.npmjs.com/package/press-any-key)

And here is an example:

```
const pressAnyKey = require('press-any-key');
pressAnyKey("Press any key to resolve, or CTRL+C to reject", {
  ctrlC: "reject"
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('You pressed any key')
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('You pressed CTRL+C')
  })
```

It runs without problems in W10.

Answer (score 4):

```
const fs = require('fs');
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
fs.readSync(0, Buffer.alloc(1), 0, 1);
```

60% of the time, it works every time.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fs = require("fs")
var fd = fs.openSync("/dev/stdin", "rs")
fs.readSync(fd, new Buffer(1), 0, 1)
fs.closeSync(fd)
```

This answer is taken from vadzim from [node.js: readSync from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430939/node-js-readsync-from-stdin)

Comment: This is UNIX-only

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but here's my hacky solution. Basically goDoWork doesn't get run until the promise resolves, which only happens when you press enter.

```
let resolv = null;
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolv = resolve;
})

var stdin = process.openStdin();
console.log('Press enter to continue');
stdin.on('data', () => {
    resolv();
    console.log("Key pressed");
});

promise.then(goDoWork);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not see an encompassing answer yet. In particular, the answers using `process.stdin.destroy()` preclude the functions being called twice if you need multiple key presses. The ones that do not call `process.stdin.off(...)` keep processing key presses. The ones that do not call `process.stdin.pause()` keep the process alive even after the program completes.

I believe the following function is pretty thorough. Called without parameters, it displays a `"Press any key to continue..."` message and waits for the user to press any key. The `message` parameter overrides the default message. The `keys` parameter allows you to listen for particular keys, and the message will repeat if other keys are pressed. The accepted key pressed is not case-sensitive unless the `keys` parameter is mixed-case.

The return value is a `Promise` with the key the user pressed (case adjusted for non-case-sensitive `keys`). The promise is rejected if they press `CTRL-c`.

```
function keyPress(message, keys) {
  const _message = message || "Press any key to continue...";
  const _keys = keys || "";
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const caseSensitive = _keys.toLowerCase() !== _keys && _keys.toUpperCase() !== _keys;
    process.stdout.write(_message);
    function keyListener(buffer) {
      let key = buffer.toString();
      if (key.charCodeAt(0) === 3) {
        process.stdin.setRawMode(false);
        process.stdin.off('data', keyListener);
        process.stdin.pause();
        // process.exit(0); // Exit process if you prefer.
        reject(key.charCodeAt(0));
      }
      const index = caseSensitive ? _keys.indexOf(key) : _keys.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase());
      if (_keys && index < 0) {
        process.stdout.write(key);
        process.stdout.write("\n");
        process.stdout.write(_message);
        return;
      }
      process.stdin.setRawMode(false);
      process.stdin.off('data', keyListener);
      process.stdin.pause();
      if (index >= 0) {
        key = _keys.charAt(index);
        process.stdout.write(key);
      }
      process.stdout.write("\n");
      resolve(key);
    }
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
    process.stdin.on('data', keyListener);
  });
}
```

Example 1: Shows `Press any key to continue...` message, waits for any key press.

```
await keyPress();
```

Example 2: Shows `Process data? (Y|N):`  message, waiting for the user to press `y`, `n`, `Y`, or `N`. Repeats the message if other key is pressed. `answer` will be either `'y'` or `'n'`, regardless of case pressed.

```
const answer = await keyPress("Process data? (Y|N): ", "yn");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') {
    process.exit();
  } else {
    console.log(`You pressed the "${str}" key`);
    console.log();
    console.log(key);
    console.log();
  }
});
console.log('Press any key...');
```

[reference](https://thisdavej.com/making-interactive-node-js-console-apps-that-listen-for-keypress-events/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, in my case, by turning the `setRawMode` to false, like this:

```
setRawMode(value) {
    if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
        process.stdin.setRawMode(value);
    }
}

confirm(settings) {
    logUtils.log(logService.createConfirmSettingsTemplate(settings));
    readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
    this.setRawMode(true);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            process.stdin.on('keypress', (chunk, key) => {
                if (chunk) { }
                resolve(key && key.name === 'y');
                this.setRawMode(false);
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            this.setRawMode(false);
            reject(false);
        }
    }).catch(this.setRawMode(false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone just looking for **Press any key to EXIT!**

```
console.log('Press any key to EXIT!');
process.openStdin().on('data',()=>{process.exit('0')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Install readline-sync in your project.

*npm install readline-sync*

Then you can use in your js

```
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
readlineSync.keyInPause();
```

It is simple.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Press any key to continue**

```js
function pressAnyKey(msg = 'Press any key to continue') {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log(msg || 'Press any key to continue');
        process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.on('data', () => {
            process.stdin.destroy();
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    await pressAnyKey();
    console.log('hello');
})();
```

```js
// timeout version

function pressAnyKey(msg = 'Press any key to continue', timeout = 3000) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let handler = null;
        const end = () => {
            process.stdin.destroy();
            if (handler) clearTimeout(handler);
            resolve();
        }
        console.log(msg || 'Press any key to continue');
        process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.on('data', end);
        handler = setTimeout(end, Math.max(1, timeout));
    });
}
```

Thanks @vkurchatkin

Answer (score -3):

I actually made an npm package called [`paktc`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/paktc) that will help you with this. If you install the package:

```
> npm install paktc
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
// your console application code here...

require('paktc') // Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Paktc does not work at all, it depends on a global called `v8debug` which don't care to research, but it's not in a normal node environment.

Comment: It's only there when a debugger is actually attached. Just tried it again in node 5, still works.

Comment: Meaning if you run `node --debug` it will only open the debugger port but will not necessarily debug unless you attach something to it. If you do, instead `node --debug-brk` then it will actually break when the process launches and attach a console debugger to it. At that point the global `v8debug` variable is found.

Comment: Lol, no. You'd have to clear the require cache and then require it again obviously.

But seriously this was my first npm library and it's terrible, lol. But I learned a lot.