# nodejs: how to press any key to continue and get the key value?

Tags: node.js

I have found some "press any key to continue" in nodejs, but I am unable to get the key that was pressed:

[press any key to continue in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687407/press-any-key-to-continue-in-nodejs)

I also found some **readline**, but this needs to have enter key pressed.

I am looking for a solution that will wait for a single press key and returns the value of the pressed key

Like:

```
let key = await waitKeyPressed(); 
console.log("You pressed key:", key);
```

Comment: The linked question is hooking the `data` event emitted by `process.stdin`, which should return either a `Buffer` or a `string` to the attached callback - what’s the issue of modifying the callback to read the value you’re after?

Comment: Just listen for the "data" event on stdin: `process.stdin.on("data", (chunk) => {});` Its not clear what you want or for what key you wait...

Answer (score 2):

Saw this question to see if there was something for easy copypastaing, turns out there wasn't, so I'll answer it now!

```js
function waitKeyPressed() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const wasRaw = process.stdin.isRaw;
        process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", (data) => {
            process.stdin.pause();
            process.stdin.setRawMode(wasRaw);
            resolve(data.toString());
        });
    });
}
```

- `setRawMode(true)` allows us to get single key presses instead of waiting for a `\n`
- `process.stdin.resume()` makes the event listener work
- `process.stdin.pause()` stops listening to stdin, so your program can exit cleanly afterwards