# Nonblocking read from a pipe in Linux

Tags: linux, pipe, ftrace

I would like to read `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe` in non-blocking way using Linux command-line tools. For instance, `cat` cannot be used, because it will be blocked. This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429369/read-file-with-timeout-in-python), with the difference that I don't want to use Python.

Comment: I've never heard of a shell command that does this.

Comment: If you don't want to use Python, how about Perl?

Comment: I am fine if there's any C language solution. The program should read whatever currently inside `trace_pipe` is and returns. If it is empty, it should immediately quite.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of ‘non-blocking’ doesn't apply to command-line tools.  However, you could run an instance of `cat` in the background by appending an ampersand to the invocation, like so:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe &
```

Now, the command returns immediately, and every time a line is readable from the file, it gets printed to the terminal (and messes up whatever you were typing).

You could also use `tail -F` if the file itself doesn't block.

Comment: This is indeed a solution, however, I would like to sample `trace_pipe` every second. Your approach increases the system load which is undesirable for my use case.

Comment: It's the same as with `cat`: if you want the command to run in the background, add an `&` at the end of the invocation.  This shouldn't increase the system load any more than running it the normal way does.