# Use a timeout to prevent deadlock when opening a file in Python?

Tags: python, file, timeout, deadlock

I need to open a file which is NFS mounted to my server. Sometimes, the NFS mount fails in a manner that causes all file operations to deadlock. In order to prevent this, I need a way to let the `open` function in python time out after a set period. E.g. something like `open('/nfsdrive/foo', timeout=5)`. Of course, the default `open` procedure has no `timeout` or similar keyword.

Does anyone here know of a way to effectively stop trying to open a (local) file if the opening takes too long?

Note: I've already tried the urllib2 module, but it's timeout options only work for web requests, not local ones.

Comment: You could try starting a timer that, when expired, sends your very process a signal -- catch that signal and deal with the failure, or stop the timer if the `open` works.  Not sure that solution would work on Windows if that's your platform -- it's a pretty Unixy approach...

Comment: Depending on the OS, there is a timeo parameter in /etc/fstab.  I suggest you kook at your man pages for that file.

Comment: If running on unix, you can use O_NONBLOCK flag with low level `os.open` to open the file and use `select.select` to wait the file ready with timeout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429369/read-file-with-timeout-in-python has some other suggestions for this type of problem, including `select` examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [stopit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stopit#timeout-context-manager)

```
from stopit import SignalTimeout as Timeout

with Timeout(5.0) as timeout_ctx:
    with open('/nfsdrive/foo', 'r') as f:
        # do something with f
        pass
```

There may be some issues with `SignalTimeout` in multithreaded environments (like Django). `ThreadingTimeout` on the other hand may cause problems with resources on some virtual hostings when you run too many "time-limited" functions

P.S. My example also limits processing time of opened file. To only limit file opening you should use different approach with manual file opening/closing and manual exception handling