# node js prompt method that'd accept, hold bunch of characters including newline

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, user-input

Which node js input/prompt method (help point out what library and function) that accept, hold bunch of characters including newline ones if, only if, clipboard is being pasted into it, not being cut out by that or any characters. else, while still regards newline characters as the end of user entry if it's being typed manually

Found common ones `process.stdin.on()` `process.stdin.once()` `readline.question()` cannot do so

Main factor is as a noob level in coding in node js environment so please help out guide to the correct, working one sincerely

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? What do you need this for? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the stdin stream on a tty, how copy-paste is handled would depend on the terminal implementation. Which terminal (on which OS) are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all text from stdin to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441025/read-all-text-from-stdin-to-a-string)